# Django How to bring data into url from DB?

Tags: python, django

****Models.py****

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class reviewData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    review_content = models.TextField()
    star_num = models.FloatField()
class buildingData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_loc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_call = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

****views.py****

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import reviewData
from .models import buildingData
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ReviewSerializer

class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = buildingData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = reviewData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

****urls.py****

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from crawling_data.views import ReviewListAPI
from crawling_data.views import BuildingInfoAPI

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/buildingdata/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
    #path('api/buildingdata/(I want to put building name here)', ReviewListAPI.as_view())

]
```

I am making review api.

I want to use building name as url path to bring reviews for specific buildings

For example, there are a, b, c reviews

a, b reviews are for aaabuilding

c reviews are for xxxbuilding

*api/buildingdata/aaabuilding (only shows aaabuilding review)*

```
{
    building_name = aaabuilding
    review_content = a
    star_num = 5

    building_name = aaabuilding
    review_content = b
    star_num = 3
}
```

*api/buildingdata/xxxbuilding (only shows xxxbuilding review)*

```
{
    building_name = xxxbuilding
    review_content = c
    star_num = 4


}
```

I've searched some dynamic url posts, but they were not that i want.

Is there any way to bring building name into url from db?

Comment: See: [URL dispatcher - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) and also [part 3 of Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/)

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py

```
path('api/buildingdata/<str:building>/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
```

And in views.py

```
class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(request, building):
        queryset = buildingData.objects.filter(building_name__contains=building)
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Hope this will solve the issue

Comment: I believe this is not what he's looking for. He wants to query reviewData based on building_name. So he wants a reviewData list for a specific building, not a list of buildings filtered by name.

Comment: Yea that's right @Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

I suggets you take a look at the django documentation, this is pretty well explained there, here is a useful [**link**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#s-writing-more-views)

In your **urls.py**, you should put:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from crawling_data.views import ReviewListAPI
from crawling_data.views import BuildingInfoAPI

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/buildingdata/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
    # added <str:building> to url
    path('api/buildingdata/<str:building>', ReviewListAPI.as_view())
]
```

And in your **views.py**:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import reviewData
from .models import buildingData
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ReviewSerializer

class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = buildingData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    # added another argument, retrieved from url
    def get(request, building):
        # changed .all() to .filter()
        queryset = reviewData.objects.filter(building_name = building)
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```